# Excel find value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have 2 excels files, need to check for a value from a cell in the other worksheet and return a cell value of a column in that worksheet. this need to be repeated for all the cells in that columns. need a vba code for this

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code.

Comment: i dont have a code..

Comment: So you want someone else to write it for you?... Not likely to get that here. Do some research, use the macro recorder. Try to adapt what the recorder provides into something more generalized. Once you've actually put some effort into your problem you are much more likely to get some help.